# Add image to left of text via css

Tags: css

How can I add an image to some text via css?

I've got this:

```
<span class="create">Create something</span>
```

and I want to add a 16x16 image to the left of that by using css. Is this possible or should i just manually add this image like so:

```
<span class="create"><img src="somewhere"/>Create something</span>
```

I'd rather not have to manually change all of the places which is why I wanted to do it via css.

thanks!

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
.create
{
background-image: url('somewhere.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 30px;  /* width of the image plus a little extra padding */
display: block;  /* may not need this, but I've found I do */
}
```

Play around with padding and possibly margin until you get your desired result.  You can also play with the position of the background image (*nod to Tom Wright) with "background-position" or doing a completely definition of "background" ([link to w3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)).

Comment: Might want to specify the position of the image. But otherwise, good call.

Comment: You can probably avoid setting the display property to block if you make sure the line-height is large enough to fit the image vertically, otherwise you'll [possibly] see it get chopped off and want to make it into a block element.

Comment: You could use the optimized option instead of the two first lines: 
background: url('somewhere.jpg') no-repeat;

Comment: This works when the page is displayed on the screen, but most browsers omit background images by default when printing so that you'll be left with a blank space where the image is supposed to be.  There must be a work-around for this!

Answer (score 44):

Very simple method:

```
.create:before {
content: url(image.png);
}
```

Works in all modern browsers and IE8+.

**Edit**

Don't use this on large sites though. The :before pseudo-element is horrible in terms of performance.

Answer (score 12):

Try something like:

```
.create
 { 
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-image: url('yourpic.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: but don't forget the *no-repeat*

Comment: Adding `width:2em; background-size: contain;` may be useful too in order to limit the size of the image.

Answer (score 9):

This works great

```
.create:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('somewhere.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: you can elaborate this though, why it works. why his code didn't etc.

Comment: Should there be something in the `url()` ?

Comment: @Darren Cook - Don't know if you're being sarcastic or not, anyway you have to put there the url to your image.

Comment: @Giovanni Not sarcasm! I just edited the answer to make it clearer that it wasn't left blank deliberately.

Answer (score 8):

For adding background icon always before text when length of text is not known in advance.

```
.create:before{
content: "";
display: inline-block;
background: #ccc url(arrow.png) no-repeat;
width: 10px;background-size: contain;
height: 10px;
}
```