# Add DIV to active menu item with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

In helping out a friend with [THIS](http://www.eggprocessinginnovations.com/site/about) site, I've managed (with plenty of SO help) to use JQuery to highlight the active menu heading when on the relevant page.  The 'active' class was added to the 'a' object of the list item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var url = window.location;
        $('#nav-menu li a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that I also need an icon to appear to the left of each menu item when it is selected (not on hover).  How can I add to the previous JQuery code to also show a DIV that is otherwise invisible?  I am open to suggestions that don't use JQuery as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735394/add-image-to-left-of-text-via-css In short, css with background image and some padding to make room for image/icon. Also have a look at sprite sheets if you have tons of little images in your site and how to use CSS to reference the correct x/y coords in a sprite to use as an image.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl didn't checked for duplicate :P.. (good point for sprites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give the class a background (if you are just giving arrows or some basic images)

Like this .

```
.active{
background: url('location') no-repeat 0% 50%;
padding: 10px //some value
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback...I moved onto other pressing issues before tackling this one again.  I've taken your advice and added the background image, but cannot move it outside of the bounds of the 'active' menu link.  I tried negative values for position but its not working...ideas?  The work: [link](http://www.eggprocessinginnovations.com/site)

Answer (score 0):

If you make a class that shows a div as not hidden, then you can use the same code you already have to add that class to the DIV that is hidden..

What I would personally do is nest the icon in the same div as the rest of the button, for example:

```
<div class="button-holder">
     <div class="icon"></div>
     <div class="button-text">Contact Page</div>
</div>
```

Then if you give the .button-holder the class .active with your JQuery you can also manipulate the .icon class

```
.button-holder {
    /*some properties*/
}
.button-holder .icon {
    /* hide the icon if .button-holder is not active*/
    display: none;
}
.button-holder.active .icon {
    /* if .button-holder is also .active make it visible */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility property of that image to true, if the link is of the active class

```
var icon_visibility = $('#link').hasClass('active') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
$('#icon').css('visibility', icon_visibility);
```