# <a><img></a> Make text appear after the image using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<a id="logon_findaP" href="javascript:findA()">Find A
    <img id="img_logon_finda" align="right" src="/mobile/Images/findA.png" alt="Find A">
</a>
```

Above is an image with anchor tag and it displays text first, image later.

Is there a way using CSS and make it display image first and text later aligned vertically?

Comment: @cchacholiades, What fiddle do you need?

Comment: i tried playing around with float and display:table, none worked

Comment: Try reading this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735394/add-image-to-left-of-text-via-css),  you can also use css pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` for the text manipulation.

Comment: If you want an image (like a logo) after your image, you can look at my fiddle code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sgruenwald/kf4p9wmk/ - It even rotates the logo.

Comment: Nope, it will be a text that is subject to localization, so <div><a><img></a></div> is the tag we are going with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following CSS rules.

```css
#logon_findaP {
   text-align: right;
} 

#img_logon_finda {
 float : left !important; 
}
```

```html
<a id="logon_findaP" href="javascript:findA()">Find A
    <img id="img_logon_finda" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0241f873cfe31b997225d46d066e6bce?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Find A">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/nj33n3o6/

Use `float: left` on the `img`.

```
#logon_findaP #img_logon_finda {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This works out when they want to be displayed inline, but in case where it requires block(vertical) it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#img_logon_finda {
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
}
#img_logon_finda:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<a id="logon_findaP" href="javascript:findA()">Find A
    <img id="img_logon_finda" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0241f873cfe31b997225d46d066e6bce?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Find A">
</a>
```

Comment: make this image first and text later